# Rounded corners through css

Tags: css

I have written one css as foolows:

```
<style>
#box_1 #box1_bg{
    width: 100px;
    padding-left:0px;
    font-family: "cachet Bold" , "CachetBoldRegular";
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:10px;
    height:30px;
    border-bottom-style:groove;
       -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
       -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
       -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
       -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;



}
</style>
```

It is giving me one box like structure..
How can i get the rounded corners for this box?

Comment: I don't understand your question, do you want _all_ the corners of this element rounded?

Comment: I assume you test in on firefox or a webkit browser? Have you tried border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.css3pie.com/ -- it's a hack for IE that give it support  for `border-radius` (and more).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using a browser that supports CSS3 you aren't going to see curved-corners. This includes all versions of IE up to and including 8. Also make sure you have a `border-color` defined so you can actualy see the border, or alternatively a `background-color`.

Comment: `border-color` does not need to be defined, `background` does

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a background or a border in order to see the rounded corners.

```
#box_1 #box1_bg{
    width: 100px;
    padding-left:0px;
    font-family: "cachet Bold" , "CachetBoldRegular";
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:10px;
    height:30px;
    border:5px groove yellow;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `border-radius:10px;` and it works in FF4, Chrome, Safari and Opera.

Alternatively you could do `border-radius:10px 3px 7px 2px` for different radii for each corner

and don't forget `background:#000;` or something to give your box some appearance

Comment: you can do `border:0px` and still have a `border-radius`, yes

Answer (score 0):

In which browser are you previewing this?

Note that the standard css3 border radius property is called `border-radius`

You are applying your rules to mozilla and webkit browsers only.

A crossbrowser selector like this should do it:

```
.round {
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:10px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:10px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
-khtml-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
-khtml-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
/* optional behavior: url(border-radius.htc) */ 
}
```

note: the .htc file is used only if you need to force support for IE6-8.

Comment: I've found the IE .htc hack to be flaky at best, on some installs, any version, IE just blows up.

Comment: Yeah, actually a way more solid solution is using PIEcss3 or conditional comments and background images (which is the most solid approach as far as I tested out). Position relative will often fix problems with .htc.

Answer (score -1):

use following styles:

```
border-radius: 10px 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-khtml-border-radius: 10px;
```

Taken from http://www.handycss.com/tips/pure-css-rounded-corners/

Comment: This makes all corners rounded. Also the border-radius should be defined as 10px.